# One cookie containing all data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookies, javascript-framework

I need to set a lot of key->value pairs inside a cookie. What I am doing as of now is saving each data point as a separate cookie which is easy but not the best optimal solution. What I would rather love to do is to have just one cookie, with all the values saved in it as a key->value pair.

I am looking for a library / wrapper which can handle create cookie / read cookie / delete cookie functions, where the actual job would be to read the master cookie, parse it, find the appropriate key value and use it.

Is there soemthing like this already present.? If not, what is the best way to do it.. I dont want to include JSON library to serialize my cookie, any other recommendation.

Thanks
Sparsh

Comment: Why do you want to store it like this? Storing them over several cookies should be better, since there is a limit to the amount of data a single cookie can hold.

Comment: Why don't you want to use JSON? The libraries are small, the data format is relatively unbloated, it is an established standard, and it allows for future development to include more complex data structures if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any 'library' to manage cookies as it's quite simple.

According to w3school (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), you can read cookies by :

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
    {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name)
        {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```

Create cookie / read cookie / delete cookie is just the manipulation of the cookie string. And update your cookie to internet navigator:

```
document.cookie=your_cookie_string
```